# How to call preprocess function for a custom template with more than one word in the template name?

Tags: theming

I have a custom module that I've defined a block with a template file.

In my modules `.module` file, I have a preprocess function...

`/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_short_login().
 */
  function mymodule_preprocess_short_login(&$variables) {
    // code
  }`

My theme file is named `short-login.html.twig`

This does not work. With other templates and preprocess functions, I have always been able to name the function by replacing the hypen (-) with an underscore (_), but this did not work for my custom template file.

To test, I renamed the template file and all the places that call it.

`/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_shortlogin().
 */
  function mymodule_preprocess_shortlogin(&$variables) {
    // code
  }`

Rename theme file... `shortlogin.html.twig`

This works and all my code executes. This is fine for a workaround, but I know there will be cases when I'd like to name my template files with more than one word.

Comment: `mymodule_preprocess_short_login` should work, as long as `short_login` is the theme hook. Can you show the code of hook_theme()?

Comment: `function mytheme_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'short-login' => [//array of variables],
  ];
}`

Comment: Just replace `-` with `_`, anything other than alphanumeric and underscores are removed (which is why your 2nd attempt works)

Comment: in hook_theme you need to use underscores in the array key (which is btw. the theme hook)

Comment: It works. Thank you. Add this as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The naming schema of the preprocess hook [`hook_preprocess_HOOK()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.3.x) contains two HOOKs.

The first one at the beginning is a module/theme name and the second at the end is a theme hook, which is an array key of the template definition in [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.3.x):

```
function hook_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'forum_display' => [
      'variables' => ['forums' => NULL, 'topics' => NULL, 'parents' => NULL, 'tid' => NULL, 'sortby' => NULL, 'forum_per_page' => NULL],
    ],
    'forum_list' => [
      'variables' => ['forums' => NULL, 'parents' => NULL, 'tid' => NULL],
    ],
    'forum_icon' => [
      'variables' => ['new_posts' => NULL, 'num_posts' => 0, 'comment_mode' => 0, 'sticky' => 0],
    ],
    'status_report' => [
      'render element' => 'requirements',
      'file' => 'system.admin.inc',
    ],
  ];
}
```

For the theme hook only alphanumeric and underscores are allowed.